# Spark: save a output HashSet to a file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following code:

```
val mySet: HashSet[String] = HashSet[String]()
val mySetBroadcastVar = sc.broadcast(mySet)

val output = input.map { t =>

  if (t.getA()!= null) {
    stSetBroadcastVar.value.add(t.getA())
  }
}.count()

sc.parallelize(myBroadcastVar.value.toList, 1).saveAsTextFile("mySetValues")
```

Then the file `mySetValues` is always empty even though it shouldn't be. Is this because `mySetValues` was saved before output was computed? How do I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Broadcast variables are to share read-only data across tasks and stagesin a efficient manner
2. Tasks are not supposed to modify broadcast variables as the updates aren't reflected either in other nodes and they aren't transported back to the driver.
3. You need accumulators for this purpose.

**Example (from spark-shell)**

```
scala> val acc = sc.accumulableCollection(scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]())
acc: org.apache.spark.Accumulable[scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String],String] = Set()

scala> val names=sc.parallelize(Seq("aravind","sam","kenny","apple"))
names: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[86] at parallelize at <console>:22

scala> names.foreach( x => if(x.startsWith("a")) acc += x )

scala> acc
res27: org.apache.spark.Accumulable[scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String],String] = Set(apple, aravind)

scala>
```

Comment: Is there an example for how to use accumulators for such scenarios? The other accumulator example I saw were basically just counters.